# How to add Anaconda base as the interpreter in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I would like to use the "base" environment of Anaconda for Pycharm. However, I cannot find this option in the list of conda environments. Where should it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Step 1:

At the bottom right of your screen, click on "Python 3.x (myProjectName)" > Add Interpreter.

[image]

#### Step 2:

Click on "Conda environment" > check "Existing Environment" > navigate to wherever you installed Anaconda at > Select the python.exe at the root of Anaconda3 directory. (i.e. ~\Anaconda3\Python.exe).

[image]

#### Step 3:

You should be using Anaconda's base environment then:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I could not find ~\Anaconda3\Python.exe. There is an "envs" folder with a list of environments, but no base. Doing a "conda env list" shows those environments and a base, but I do not see it in Pycharm. I am using MacOS, btw

Comment: What is the output of `conda env list`? It'll show you where you installed anaconda3

Comment: Also, try executing `~/somePathYouInstalled/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate` or `conda activate base`

Comment: I found it actually. For some reason it wasn't in the list, and it was in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone is wondering how to do this for MacOS. The path is ...anaconda3/python.app for python interpreter.